# Storing private/secret keys in an Ionic application

Tags: ionic-framework, cryptography

How do you go about storing private/secret keys in an Ionic application? I know that with a generic Android application, it is possible with the [Android Keystore API](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Storing-Secret-Keys-in-Android) or [Keychain Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH203-TP1).

**Some context:** I am trying to develop an offline payments protocol that works on the basis of Message Authentication Codes (MAC) which establish an agreement between the payer and payee. This protocol enables value to be transferred from Alice to Bob by copying 8 digits in one direction and 8 digits in another. The code is computed using secret keys assigned to each participant, which is based on several parameters. Each instance of the application will need to generate its own secret key for the user, which acts as a unique identifier and a basis for the application.

Comment: Have you found anything yet?

Comment: Nope not at all 

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same use case, need to be capable to decrypt an encrypted key generated on the backend server, while having no internet connection. I managed to solve this copying the RSA key used for encryption directly on the app source code, but as I was reading is not difficult to access the code from the .apk or the .ipa

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SecureStorage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/secure-storage) It does have some limitations but should work for your requirement